# Wordpress Multisite on multiple sub-domains

Tags: multisite

I need to setup WP multisite in a fashion:

```
blog.mydomain.com
blog.mydomain.co.uk
blog.mydomain.it
blog.mydomain.hu
```

Is there a specific way to get this working? I've read about approaches like `it.mydomain.com, hu.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com/it, mydomain.com/hu` but I haven't found an example that would solve my problem. The main domain `mydomain.com` will be running something completely different, so I need WP just to handle the blog part `blog.mydomain`. I guess I'll also need some language plugin like Polylang.

Thanks

Comment: With the latest WordPress, it should be no problem to setup your multisite in the fashion you have described (as long as domains are mapped correctly). Have you tested it already? As for multi language: sadly it is off topic for this Q&A as it is not in core yet. [MultilingualPress](https://multilingualpress.org/) should work for this, as it is designed for multisite (polylang/WPML/.. are as far as I know not).

Comment: Multisite gives you multiple separate sites on the same install. If those domains all have the same site but at different addresses then that is not what multisite was intended to do. Note that if your problem is that you want to translate your site and have the translated version available at a different URL, you should have asked how to do that. Ask how to solve your problem, not how to implement your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the right approach for this problem.

Here, you're talking about 4 **domains**, not **subdomains**. Subdomains are what usually replace the www in an url.

And, if you create a multisite network, then you won't need to have a multilingual plugin since you plan on having only one language per website.

**Having a multisite network is useful if you plan on having a different content for each website** of the network. However, if you plan on having the same content in different languages, then I'll advise against it.

If you want to have the same content in different languages, you should only create one WordPress website with a multilingual plugin such as WPML or Polylang. It will save you some time as translating a page/post is easier than recreating it on another website.

Regarding the website url for each language, it's also easy to set up. I know that at least WPML includes this natively and gives you tutorials to set up your DNS for that purpose.

So, as a result, I would suggest :

- Create a single website with a multilingual plugin
- Setup your different domains to redirect to a specific language version of your website

Comment: I guess each language version will have the same posts but in their respective language but there's no restriction like that. There could be a case when for example I might want to add a post just for the UK but not have it for the rest of the countries. From experience the multiple versions usually start off as copies but can diverge in the future so that's the main reason I wanted to stay away from simple redirects.